# removing distortions created by adobe lightroom's fill edges mode

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-lightroom, merge

I did a Panorama Merge with Fill Edges checked off in Adobe Lightroom and it mostly worked great but there are weird distortions in the top left corner and top center.

[image]

Any idea how I might most effectively remove these distortions with Adobe Photoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content-Aware Fill is good for this type of job.

[image]

[image]

You could go completely overboard & use Luminar AI to replace the sky completely [& I warmed it all up a bit too ;)

[image]